# Why does passing arguments by reference work in C++ the way it does?

Tags: c++, syntax, reference

Let's say I have a function:

```
void function(int& i){};
```

and a variable:

```
int j = 2;
```

I know that I can use my function:

```
function(j);
```

But it is inconsistent: the compiler should notice that the function expects a reference, not a normal variable and that I tried to use a normal variable instead (*int& != int*) and abort the compilation. However, people who invented C++ implemented this behaviour. It seems illogical to me.

Why is it possible? Is there something I don't understand or is the sytax of C++ really inconsistent?

Note: I'm **not** asking when I should pass arguments by value ad when by reference or what's the difference between these methods (there are pleny materials covering this topic). I just want to know why it works the way it does - the syntax seems contradictory to me.

**Why don't I need a reference to pass an argument by reference?:**

```
int& k = j;
function(k);
```

**Edit:** I don't have ny doubts about binding references to variables, I think the following piece of code is clear and logical:
    int& k = j;

The only doubts I have refer to passing arguments by references:

```
void function(int& i){};
int j = 2; 
function(j);
```

Comment: This is fundamental CS - See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy

Comment: @EdHeal, what is CS? Computer science? I read the artice, but I see no answer to my question. It has been wrtten that the program evaluates arguments first and after that it evaluates the function. But how does it help me?

Comment: Your understanding of passing by reference vs passing by value.

Comment: I agree with you. This is one of C++ inconsistencies. Just like using templates in templates where you have to delimit nested template types with spaces to avoid confusion with bit shift operators.

Comment: @nsilent22, That has been fixed for over four years.

Comment: @Ed Heal, CS does not stand for my understanding of passing by reference vs. passing by value. What does it stand for?

Comment: @chris, how has it been fixed?

Comment: While it's arguably not ideal that you can pass by (non-const) reference with exactly the same syntax as passing by value, I don't see what's inconsistent about it.

Comment: @user2738748, Taking an example, `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` is parsed properly instead of being a right shift operator at the end. This has been the case since 2011 with C++11.

Comment: @chris: here is the inconsistence I see: I define a function which takes a reference (int &) as an argument. But then I can pass a normal variable (int) to it. So I ignore the "reference" part of the argument of the function.

Comment: @chris, I see how it has been fixed in your example. But how has the inconsistence been shift in case of passing arguments by reference?

Comment: `int& k = j;` - **Why shouldn't `j` be required to be a reference here, then?** Because references are freakin' supposed to refer to variables/objects. References "bind" - same for reference as function parameter.

Comment: Passing an int to a function(int&), the compiler will interpret this as passing  the int by reference.  If you attempt to define both function(int&) and function(int) the compiler will fail due to ambiguity.

Comment: Exactly. If parameters of reference type would need to bind to another reference, I would find it consistent for a variable with reference type to need to bind to another reference. It's not even like `int` needs an `int` to be passed - it can take `double`, `char`, and a whole bunch of other types.

Comment: chris: C taught me that language syntax is something that doesn't need "fixing".

Comment: @ LogicStuff , I have no doubts about the piece of code you wrote - see my edit. It wasn't my question.

Comment: @chris, could you explain your point? I don't get it.

Comment: @user2738748, My point is the same as LogicStuff. Reference parameters work the same way as reference variables. That's perfectly consistent. If everything you passed in had to match the parameter exactly for consistency, there would be no implicit conversions (e.g., passing a string literal in place of a `std::string` wouldn't work). I'm not saying the syntax for passing by reference is great, but at least it's consistent with the other uses of a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why don't I need a reference to pass an argument by reference?

The *short* version is that all the ways that matter here, `i` effectively *already is* a reference.

The long version is that when you declare an argument of type `int&`, this does *not* mean "an integer reference". It means "an integer *lvalue*", which is a different thing. An integer reference is only one way to produce an integer lvalue- there are others, as you've noticed. C++ expression value categories and types interact but are *not* the same system. `i` is an integer lvalue; therefore it will accept that as the argument.

Answer (score 1):

A reference isn't an object by itself, it just creates another name for an object. An alias.

With `int& k = j;` you say that `k` and `j` are different names for the same object. This is similar to `person& Bob = Robert;`, when using a nickname for a person.

So, why would it then make a difference if you pass `k` or `j` as a parameter to the function? They are the same thing. Just like Bob and Robert.

Comment: Because when I define a function: *void function(int& i){};*, I say  to the complier *expect a reference to an integer as the argument of this function*. I agree, that *k* and *j* are different names for the same object (or a person), but in your example "Rober" is the true name of Robert, and Bob is his nickname. So when I say that my function expects only a nickname, why can I also use the true name?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is so clear. The c++ compiler doesn't take '&' like a reference. They are both the same func(int &a) or func(int a). The compiler takes it like a variable in the two situations. But if you define the func like func(int *a) that means I want the address of the 'a' argument. Did you see the diffirence. The compiler hierarchy of c++ is a little bit diffirent from the c compiler.

Comment: @Kevin, I said nothng about pointers, I think I understand why functions with pointers as arguments work the way they do. And if functions *func(int &a)* and * func(int a)* are the same, how can the compiler distinguish them - they work differently?

Comment: I said the compiler distinguish them because of the hierarchy of compiler. But I think this answer is not enough for you that's way I suggets you that link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: @Kevin, I said nothing about C. It's certainly a good topic to read about, but my question referes to C++ only.